# Do any python tools exist for rolling over log/configuration files?

Tags: python, configuration, rollover

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. modify a default configuration file on a local machine (Thing.conf).
2. save the previous config file on a virtual client to something like Thing.conf.1, and keep track of the previous 10 or so conf files. (Thing.conf.2, Thing.conf.3, etc.)
3. push that configuration file to the remote virtual client (/etc/thing/Thing.conf).

to be clear -- step 2 is the crux of the problem here, step 1 and 3 are just for context.

Comment: can you just put your file under version control? http://mercurial.selenic.com/

Comment: Is this question related to `python` ?

Comment: If this a generic problem, i.e. not for an application coded in Python, then you're probably better off just using [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). If it is for an application coded in Python then @MattiLyra's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @dm03514 it's not possible for us as then it would involve a commit and push every time the code is run, which would be sub-optimal for a number of reasons in our framework

Comment: @jvivenot yes I am looking for a python tool that does this (see title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python `logging` framework has a [`RotatingFileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=logging.handlers#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler), it also allows you force a rollover with `RotatingFileHandler.doRollover()`. I'm not sure if that's what you're after though. It'll allow you to roll over the log (config?) files on the virtual client where the logging is presumably being done.